# Android service active even after unbind called

Tags: android, android-service-binding

In my android app, parent activity launch a service on a user action using

```
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

In service I receive location updates(implementing LocationListener).

I also provide a STOP button on UI which enables user to kill the service.

```
unbindService(mConnection);
```

This action calls onDestroy() method of the service.
What I observe is that even when I press STOP button(thus unbinding the service, and hence destroying it), onLocationChanged() is still getting called repeatedly.

How is it even possible when service has been unbinded, and destroyed?

Comment: you've probably missed unregistering the location listener in your service.

Comment: ok...but if the listener object itself is destroyed then how can a method still be called on it?

Comment: onDestroy does not mean GC. if there is a thread running and referencing that object, it will hang around.

Comment: I agree with your explanation. Thanks a lot.